# Calendar follow scroll but it should remain attached to the field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two divs that scroll separately.

http://jsfiddle.net/kv8ggqm7/1/

If I open the calendar (field DATE) and scroll, the calendar
follow the scroll but it should remain attached to the field.

If I uncomment the line

`$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('position','fixed');`

it seems to work but if I scroll to bottom, open the calendar
and scroll to top the calendar disappear and if I click on the data field it doesn't appear.

The calendar is datepicker of jQueryUI (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Using css like

```
#ui-datepicker-div
{
     position : fixed !important;
}
```

I don't get the expected result.

Any help would be approciated

Comment: If you switch the `fixed` for `absolute`, does that fix your problem? Also note that when you want to use `position: absolute`, the parent element has to have a `position: relative` or `position: fixed`.

Comment: It doesn't fix my problem.. The parent of the calendar  (added automatically) is body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is define the css in the css folder like this:

media screens can be really usefull in making a responsive design. For more information look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #secondDiv{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    Right: 0px;
  }
}
```

remove this jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#calendar').datepicker();

/* remove this part */
/*
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).width() > 480)
    {
         //$('#ui-datepicker-div').css('position','fixed');
         $('#secondDiv').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());

    }

   });    
*/
});
```

Because the css is loaded after everything is loaded the picker reacts different on the css

Comment: Ok but the secondDiv is not really fixed..it follows the scroll

Comment: @Pierminator What do you mean, i made this for you: http://jsfiddle.net/kv8ggqm7/2/ If I look at that it doesnt follow the scroll, or do you want prevent scrolling when your mous is on that div?